# Handling input of switch makes state from array into object

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have multiple switches that I handle in one array and when I log the type of the array it's object when it should have been array.

```
function insertApousies(userids, period, date) {
    console.log(typeof userids);
    // Output: [ 44, 4475 ]
}
```

Here is the switch handler that I have:

```
const [absent, setAbsent] = useState([]);

const toggleSwitch = () => {
    if(absent.includes(id)) {
        setAbsent(absent.filter((absense) => absense != id));
    } else {
        setAbsent((absenses) => [...absenses, id]);
    }
}
```

I tried using `Array.from(userids)` and the deconstructing method: `const users = ...userids`;

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Where the userids and absent come from? Please post all the relavent code.

Comment: `console.log(typeof userids);` => `[ 44, 4475 ]` is not possible, please check the output of the console log again.

Comment: @Abe - Not sure how it's not possible since that is what it outputs

Comment: @CodeThing - the come from the frontend. userids is the backend and that's where I log the type of it and absent comes from the frontend where it's stored using a state. Adding more code now